# Projectile trajectory with linear air resistance

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, projectile, drag

I have the following equations

$$\ x′′(t)=−\frac km  x′(t)$$

$$\ y′′(t)=−\frac km  y′(t) - g$$

where $k$ is the drag, $m$ is the mass of the object and $t$ is the time. $g$ is the gravity constant.

After integrating the functions twice, I end up with the following equations

$$\ x(t) = C_1  e^{\frac {-kt} {2}} + C_2$$
$$\ y(t) = C_3  e^{\frac {-kt} {2}} + C_4 - \frac {gmt}{k}$$

How should I determine the constants $C_1$, $C_2$ etc? I want to be able to set the angle $\alpha$ and velocity $v_0$.

For example $y'(0) = 30 \sin(\alpha)$

Comment: First check your integrations, you have mistakes on that. And just some pedantic observation: you should have more integration constants, but it looks like that you already applied some not mentioned initial conditions.

Comment: @Ignacio Sorry forgot two signs. More than four integration constants in total?

Comment: Should the first term in your second differential equation depend on $y'(t)$ rather than $x'(t)$?

Comment: @BMS Yes, now I hope everything is in order. :)

Comment: There are 4 unknowns $C_1,C_2,C_3,C_4$, and there are 4 initial conditions $x(0)=A,y(0)=B,x'(0)=C,y'(0)=D$. So you have all the info you need to determine the $C_k$.

Comment: You will have four constants because you have two second degree differential equations. Now, you still have error in both integrations... it's not just putting an extra constant blindly. And BTW, the exponent is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I think this problem is sufficiently general to merit writing an explicit answer.  My preference for formalizing the initial conditions are:

$$ x(0) = 0,
y(0) = 0 \\
x'(0) = v_x, 
y'(0) = v_y \\ $$

I believe the solutions are:

$$ x(t) = -\frac{v_x m}{k} \left( {{\rm e}^{-{\frac {kt}{m}}}}-1 \right)  \\
y(t) = - \frac{m}{k^2} \left(  \left( gm+{\it v_y}\,k \right)  \left( {{\rm e}^{-{\frac 
{kt}{m}}}}-1 \right) +gtk \right)  $$

You can put things in terms of the initial velocity and launch angle if you desire.  That should not be difficult.